# Squashing a .swf file to under 40kb

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, actionscript, filesize

I recently took up a job creating a video ad banner to advertise on a major website, but they require that the swf uploaded is under 40kb in it's 'initial flash load'. This would be fine, except the video player itself is around 50kb, even though the actual video is loaded externally.

I've already optimised the ad as much as possible and got it to 86kb, so is there any way to reduce the file size further?

Comment: Is the video loaded from an external source (.flv/f4v/mov file for example) or is the video embedded in the swf ? Also, I see the question is tagged as3. You're sure you're not using actionscript2 right (the flvplayback component in that one was quite chunky). What are you using to playback the video ? (simple actionscript (NetConnection) or a component (if so, which)) ?

Comment: If you omit the component and instead run with the Video class (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html), your file size should be smaller.

Comment: 40kbs really? Do your employers think everyone is still using a Commodore 64?

Comment: You could remove all the unneeded SWC that flash adds by default, leaving only global.swc. Also remove unneeded embedded fonts/characters if you have any.

Comment: @andygoestohollywood - it's most likely a requirement of the ad platform not OP's employer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. any images make sure they are compressed as much as possible while looking acceptable
2. textfields, dont embed all the font glyphs, embed only the characters you need
3. any embedded audios, make sure they are compressed
4. remove any libraries that are not used
5. remove the UIComponent flv player which adds a lot of space and create it with code, this will save a ton of code for you

example:
http://blog.martinlegris.com/2008/06/03/tutorial-playing-flv-video-in-plain-as3-part-1/